# Is there any algorithm that can include rule based data association for spatial clustering?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-processing

Consider a group of events A,B,C and D. These events are related to each other and this can be defined through a set of rules like -

- A is followed by B or D and never C.
- If B occurrs twice in 5 minutes, C is triggered. 
  .. and so on.

The dataset I have has more than a 10000 rows where each record consists of the geographic coordinates, timestamp and an event that occurred at that time. I want to cluster these data points based on the rules as mentioned above but I'm not sure how to do it. The threshold factors to prevent all the events from being grouped together could be decided based on the time intervals or spatial difference. 
How can these rules be represented and be used as a deciding factor during clustering?
So far I've tried clustering based on the spatial and temporal factors using algorithms like ST-DBSCAN and Clustream but I'd really like to find a way to group the data points based on the event sequences according to the rules.

Comment: Did you try to do it in two steps: (1) Build clusters using the geographic coordinates, ignoring the rules; (2) Split each cluster into subclusters using the rules, ignoring the geographic coordinates.

Comment: @Stef I haven't tried that approach yet. What can I use to split the subclusers based on the rules?

Comment: Well, just try to minimise the number of groups needed so that each group obeys the rules.

Comment: I would also suggest the same as Stef; however, I'd like to add that what Stef proposed is an informal approach to solving the issue (mostly heuristic.) The approach could be made rigorous via a decomposition technique. This is typically done by formalising your problem as a joint optimization problem (i.e. adding your rules as constraints to the clustering optimization problem) then splitting the problem into two steps via a Lagrange multiplier technique, which (depending on the decomposition used) can give you bounds on how close to an optimum solution you approach.

Comment: The main difference between the informal & formal approach is that the (formal) decomposition will iterate back and forth just as the informal approach; however with each iterate it will make adjustments to the corresponding subproblem's objective to (hopefully) bring you closer to the optimal solution (of your joint optimization.)

Comment: @ldog I am not familiar with this approach but I will check it out.  Thank you.

Comment: @Stef Got it. Thank you.

Comment: @vnk In any case, it's an interesting problem, and when you do have a working solution please do tell us about it :)